# Unable in running Project from Tomcat to Glassfish server in Netbeans

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, glassfish-3

I made a Java web project using Tomcat server.Now I am opening the same project in another PC where only Glassfish is installed(Due to some reasons I don't wanna run the project using Tomcat anymore).But it gives this exception now.

> Exception during lifecycle processing
>
> Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to add listener of type: com.chat.listeners.ChatAppListener, because it does not implement any of the required ServletContextListener, ServletContextAttributeListener, ServletRequestListener, ServletRequestAttributeListener, HttpSessionListener, or HttpSessionAttributeListener interfaces

Answer (score 1):

Is there any warning when you opening the project in netbeans.Right click on the project , select resolve server missing problem.Choose Glassfish server.Run once again.

Comment: I resoved the missing server problem but same error.

Comment: @TruePS just try a Clean and Build by right click on the project .

Comment: GlassFish Server is perfectly working?.Try it with a sample project by creating a new project.

Answer (score 0):

You have apache specific relations in your web.xml file (like file handler servlets). 
That is why glassfish can't start your application.